# change texture based on neighborn instances in godot 4

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to make a 2D farm simulator, when instantiating 'plant' it is created with an initial texture of 1 square. but when making another instance next to it, I want it to use another atlas texture to combine both textures and look better.

I need to be able to go through the instances and check for other surrounding positions so I can change their texture as needed.

I tried using (var instances =get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Dirt")) however doing a for loop to check the results and change their textures if they were in a position close to the block vector did not work.

This is My "Dirt" instance:

```
extends Area2D
const Corn = preload("res://assets/Objects/Farming/Corn/corn_growth2.tscn")
var timer = Timer.new()
var has_seed = false

func _on_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if !has_seed:
        if Input.is_action_pressed("plant_action"):
            var Corn1 = Corn.instantiate()
            Corn1.position = Vector2(0,0)
            self.add_child(Corn1)
            has_seed = true

func cambiarRegion(x: float, y: float) -> void:
    var texture_atlas: AtlasTexture = $Sprite2D.texture
    var region_size: Vector2 = Vector2(16, 16)
    var new_region_rect = Rect2(Vector2(x, y), region_size)
    texture_atlas.region = new_region_rect
    $Sprite2D.texture = texture_atlas
```

[FOR LOOP AND INSTANCES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ3eS.png)

Comment: You may want to look into using a Tilemap with [terrain sets](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html#handling-tile-connections-automatically-using-terrains). Autotile can automatically set the texture based on the neighbouring tiles.

Comment: I initially thought about it, however I'm new to Godot, so I don't know if I can add scripts to "plant" a tilemap, as if it were an instance.